# Is it possible to call into C functions from OCaml, without wrapped types?

Tags: c, assembly, compilation, ocaml, ffi

I'm trying to write a (desperately tiny, simple — I have no idea what I'm doing, let's be real!) compiler in OCaml.

I'd really like to avoid checking *any* ISO-C code into the project (despite knowing C fairly well; the goal here is to learn and use OCaml exclusively.) Pursuant to this, I need to write a “runtime” for the compiled language in OCaml, compile it separately from the primary project, and then link it against the compiler-itself's output.

Unfortunately, it looks like *any* external functions — even ones that don't touch any OCaml data-structures / the OCaml heap, are expected to be constructed using OCaml's C macros:

```
CAMLprim value scheme_entry(value unit) {
    int i;
    i = 42;
    return Val_int(i);
}
```

This probably isn't an option, if I'm emitting the assembly instructions myself. (At least, not until I learn quite a bit more!)

Is there *any* way (including hacky ones — this is a personal learning project) to invoke extremely simple functions like the following from OCaml?

```
_scheme_entry:
    movl $42 %eax
    ret
```

> For reference, I'm working through Ghuloum's IACC: http://ell.io/tt$ocameel

Comment: As far as I understand, Ocaml isn't meant to be used with machine level instructions, for portability reasons. Thus there aren't any way of inlining assembly code from Ocaml directly. Furthermore, the ABI isn't set in stone, and may change overtime. You can still try to figure out the runtime calling conventions, and provide obj files to the OCaml compiler if you want (that's what happens ultimately when using C code).

Answer (score 3):

> Unfortunately, it looks like any external functions — even ones that don't touch any OCaml data-structures / the OCaml heap, are expected to be constructed using OCaml's C macros:

No, they are not. If your function doesn't touch OCaml at all, or doesn't allocated or works with the allocated values, then you can call functions directly, e.g.,

```
value scheme_entry(value unit) {
    int i;
    i = 42;
    return Val_int(i);
}
```

and on OCaml side:

```
external scheme_entry : unit -> int = "scheme_entry" [@@noalloc]
```

In the latest releases of OCaml we got even more control, so that we can pass floats and bigger integers without boxing/unboxing. Read [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html#s%3AC-cheaper-call) for the further info.

Note, that `Val_int` is just a macro that shift a C integer one bit to the left and sets the least significant bit to one, i.e., `(((unsigned)(x) << 1)) + 1)`. So, if you don't need to translate OCaml integers to C integers and vice verse, then you don't even need to use this macros, so you runtime can be totally unaware of OCaml, for example:

```
 void runtime_init(void) {
    printf("Hello from runtime");
 }
```

and on OCaml side:

```
 val runtime_init : unit -> unit = "runtime_init" [@@noalloc]
```

Note: the `[@@noalloc]` attribute was added in OCaml 4.03, before that version, you should use `"noalloc"`, e.g.,

```
 val runtime_init : unit -> unit = "runtime_init" "noalloc"
```

Of course, your extremely simple function should obey the C calling convention that is appropriate to your particular architecture and operating system. So if your function destroys some registers that should be preserved, you should expect troubles, for example on amd64 ABI you should preserve rbp, rbx, r12-r15. There is nothing OCaml specific with this requirement, just a normal C calling convention.

Comment: Although the above answer about the `ctypes` library is almost certainly what I need — one quick question about your still-excellent explanation: what about the `Val_int` macro? The entire point of my question (although it appears I asked poorly!) is to avoid the bits of interacting-with-OCaml-externally that *require C code* (for instance, Val_int, which depends on OCaml headers, which thus must be written in C) — so that I can compile that ‘external code’ myself.

Comment: Somehow failed to ask an actual question there. Let's phrase it this way: are `Val_int` and similar stable, i.e. defined-not-to-change? If so, I could implement them compiler-side, so the compiled assembly can call into (or be called by) the compiled-OCaml runtime, without any C “glue” …

Comment: Well, it's stable, but it wouldn't be right to use OCaml integers for your compiler. You should use `nativeint` and use the `unboxed` attribute. Then normal machine integers will be passed to and from external functions.

Comment: and there is no need to use ctypes here. They will introduce a lot of intermediate translations (on the fly in OCaml - that is an answer to a question whether it is possible to do on the compiler side). Since you will operate with machine words and floats you don't need any translations at all.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into using the [ctypes library](https://github.com/ocamllabs/ocaml-ctypes) and associated packages, which are available through OPAM.

```
opam install ctypes ctypes-foreign posix-types
```

Example:

```
open Foreign
open Ctypes
open Posix_types

let getpid = foreign "getpid" (void @-> returning pid_t)
let () = Printf.printf "%d\n" (Pid.to_int (getpid ()))
```

(Compiling this requires the packages `ctypes`, `ctypes.foreign`, and `posix-types`.)