# OCaml: How can I get the path to the *current module* / my project's directory?

Tags: unix, compiler-construction, ocaml, filepath

I'm new to OCaml, but I'm trying to figure out the equivalent of `__filename`, `__dirname` from Node. That is, I need to build a path *relative* to the file containing the code in question.

---

For reference, I'm working through Ghuloum's IACC: http://ell.io/tt$ocameel

I'm building my first compiler, and I have an utterly-simplistic ‘runtime’ file (in C — [temporarily](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46566761/31897)) adjacent to the compiler's source-code. I need to be able to pass the path to this file, as an argument (or a pre-compiled version, I suppose) to `gcc` or my linker, to have it linked against my compiler's output when I invoke the linker/assembler tooling.

(This may be a stupid question — I'm at a bit of an unknown-unknown here, “how does a compiler get the runtime *to* the linker”, or something like that. Any commentary about idiomatic solutions to this is welcome, even if it's not a direct answer to the above question!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running the source file directly via `ocaml myfile.ml`, `Sys.argv.(0)` will give you the path to the source file and you can use `Filename.dirname` to get the directory from that.

If you first compile the source file into an executable and then run the executable, `Sys.argv.(0)` will give you the name of the executable. In that scenario it's impossible to get the location of the source code (especially if you consider that the person running the executable might not even have the source code on their system).

If you set up your project structure, so that your sources live in src/, your compiled binary in bin/ and the compiled stdlib in lib/, you could just use `Filename.dirname Sys.argv.(0) ^ "../lib"` as the library path for `gcc`. This will work whether you run `ocaml src/mycompiler.ml`, `bin/mycompiler` or just `mycompiler` after installing everything to `/usr/` or `/usr/local/`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I started to worry about, halfway through my question. I guess I need to figure out how compiler-writers go about shipping additional resources to their users. I guess I might have to inline the text (or object to link to?) into the binary? :x Thanks nonetheless, this is a good answer for scripting situations!

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE If you project is laid out as described in my last paragraph, it should just work with `argv.(0)`. If you have additional resources that you need to access, you can put them in share/ and do the same thing. Note that if your stdlib is dynamically linked and you don't install to a standard path, you'll also need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to find the .so when running the compiled binary, but that's an unrelated problem.

Comment: doesn't dune sets some env variables that you can use to get the path to the module?